# Mounting external harddisk

Tags: mount

When I mount USB memory sticks, there is no problem. But when I mount external harddisks, there are two problems.

First, it seems that it's recognized by chance. I usually have to try a few times before it can be recognized.

Second, after long time of idle, the external harddisks will be disconnected automatically.

Anyone can help? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3.

Comment: Are those **external harddisks** also connected over USB?

Comment: @M.Dm. Yes, USB.

Comment: I have 2 portable harddisks similar to yours and after some idle period they sort of hibernate. Maybe that is the reason why your Ubuntu system thinks they are disconnected.

Comment: sounds like a bad cable or failing controller on the HDD

Comment: @ravery I have 3 external harddisks and they all have the same problem.